# 2017 MBP, no dust, hot enough to fry an egg

Tags: macbook-pro, temperature

I have a 2017 MBP which works reasonably well, but it seems to have a heating issue. I've opened it and found there was very little dust inside, but I cleaned out whatever little bit there was. Now my MBP seems to have two modes: (1) frying pan on my lap. (2) fans running full blast. I've installed a fan controller app to avoid over-heating but this just makes the fans run more than the default settings allow.

Most advice I can find online says to clean out the dust or get a cooling pad. Is there really no fix for this hot slab of metal or my fans running full blast? I'm not afraid of opening it up and poking at stuff if I need to.

Comment: This is an often occurring question on this site (and on the web in general). Could you please [edit] your question to show your [research](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)? Also, are you doing something computationally intensive when the machine runs hot? Are you in a very warm location?

Comment: What CPU / GPU is in your Pro? If anything isn’t stock, let us know as well.

Comment: @bmike 2.3 GHz Dual-Core Intel Core i5, Intel Iris Plus Graphics 640 1536 MB

Comment: these are  the current issues that many people face especially with the newest intel Macs. you can trade in your Mac and buy a M2 MacBook.

Answer (score -1):

Reset your PRAM and SMC. Those can sometimes make cooling a little wonky.

PRAM:

- Shut down your computer and disconnect all USB devices (except wired keyboards).
- Press the power button to turn on your Mac.
- Immediately press and hold the Option, Command, P, and R keys on your keyboard. You need to press this key combination before the gray screen appears or it won’t work.
- Hold down these keys for 20 seconds, during which time your Mac will appear to restart.

Once you hear the startup chime for the 2nd time, release the buttons. Your Mac will now restart and some basic settings like volume will be reset.

If that doesn't work, reset your SMC as well. Check [this site](https://www.avast.com/c-reset-mac-pram-smc) for specifics, as your exact model will matter.

After resetting both, your issue should be resolved as long as it isn't a hardware issue like a temperature sensor going stupid.

Also, I've used [Macs Fan Control](https://crystalidea.com/macs-fan-control) before and it works really well at letting you control your fans.

I hope at least one of those helps!